# Add specific attribute and values to input and label html tags in Woocommerce

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce, attributes

I'm trying to add style, depending on whether the checkbox is clicked. This code is missing "id" and "for" for input and label (line 11). Logical decision to add generation of numbers. How to do it correctly?

```
foreach ($choices as $choice) {
    $attr = '';
    $key_val = explode("|", $choice);
    /* It has to be two items ( Value => Label ), otherwise don't proceed */
    if (count($key_val) == 2) {
        if (in_array(trim($key_val[0]), $defaults)) {
            $attr = 'checked';
        }
        /* For admin field, we don't need <li></li> wrapper */
        $html .= (($_ptype != "wccaf") ? '<li>' : '') . '<input type="checkbox" data-has_field_rules="'.$has_field_rules.'" data-is_pricing_rules="'.$_is_pricing_rules.'" class="' . $_ptype . '-field ' . $_class . '" name="' . esc_attr($_meta["name"] . $_index) . '[]" value="' . esc_attr(trim($key_val[0])) . '" ' . $attr . ' ' . $_ptype . '-type="checkbox" ' . $_ptype . '-pattern="mandatory" ' . $_ptype . '-mandatory="' . $_meta["required"] . '" ' . $_readonly . ' /><label class="wcff-option-wrapper-label">' . esc_attr(trim($key_val[1])) . '</label>' . (($_ptype != "wccaf") ? '</li>' : '');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated**

Try the following (untested), that will add a `for` attribute + value to the `<label>` and an `id` attribute + value to the `<input>`:

```
foreach ($choices as $choice) {
    $attr = '';
    $key_val = explode("|", $choice);
    /* It has to be two items ( Value => Label ), otherwise don't proceed */
    if (count($key_val) == 2) {
        if (in_array(trim($key_val[0]), $defaults)) {
            $attr = 'checked';
        }
        $sprintf = sprintf( '<input type="checkbox" %s %s %s %s %s %s %s /><label %s class="wcff-option-wrapper-label">%s</label>',
            'id="' . esc_attr($_meta["name"] . $_index) . '"',
            'data-has_field_rules="'.$has_field_rules.'"',
            'data-is_pricing_rules="'.$_is_pricing_rules.'"',
            'class="' . $_ptype . '-field ' . $_class . '"',
            'name="' . esc_attr($_meta["name"] . $_index) . '[]"',
            'value="' . esc_attr(trim($key_val[0])) . '"',
            $attr . ' ' . $_ptype . '-type="checkbox" ' . $_ptype . '-pattern="mandatory' . $_meta["required"] . '" ' . $_readonly,
            'for="' . esc_attr($_meta["name"] . $_index) . '"',
        esc_attr(trim($key_val[1]) ) );

        $html .= $_ptype != "wccaf" ? '<li>'.$sprintf.'</li>' : $sprintf;
    }
}
```

I have embedded the code in a `sprintf()` function to make it more readable, functional and easy to tune.